Is there any way to analyze the whole python code with pylint, even if there is syntax error? If there is syntax error it always gets stuck at that
I'm trying to analyze python code with pylint , but if there is any syntax error on the code pylint only shows that syntax error,as it gets stuck parsing the whole code and does not show other issues. Is there any way to work around with this?
I'm expecting to run the whole code with pylint even if there is syntax errors and show all the issues there is.

Why not fix that syntax error and run the linter again?

It's like asking someone to check for spelling mistakes in a language they can't actually read.

A syntax error prevents the entire program from making any sense. It's like asking someone to check that the wallpaper matches before the house is even built.

Is there any way to work around with this? No.  When there is a syntax error, pylint can't make sense of the rest of the code.

I needed it analyze mined repositories from github and make datasets of code even if there was syntax errors. So I was hoping to find a way to work around this issue. If there is any other tools that can solve this issue please do tell me

The python's ast builtin module cannot parse your code if there's a syntax error. Any linter based on it won't be able to do that, and pylint is one of them. ruff had to introduce a custom hand-written recursive descent parser in order to be able to recover on syntax error.

i installed ruff but it still seems get stuck on syntax errors, am I missing something about using this functionality? I already upgraded ruff too

ruff could do it with this new parser, it's not doing it yet. You need to fix the syntax error to benefit from the other lint right now.
